# Git: how to reset untracked files?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset, git-untracked, git-track

I made a commit, then changed some files in my project, then did `git reset --hard HEAD`. It said `untracked files` for all the files I had added. How do I resolve this so that those files are tracked and get reset along with the rest of the project?

Comment: Just add them back: `git add`

Comment: This worked, thanks! Feel free to post as a reply so I can approve.

Comment: No problem. I also added some more detail in the answer.

Comment: Helps to know what tracked / untracked _means_. Basically it means is / isn't in the Index.

Answer (score 1):

Some more details on my comment:

The command performed by gkeenley with the `--hard` option tells git to not only reset HEAD, that is, their last commit but also the index (where git "caches" changes to files and trees) as well as the working tree.
Thus `git add` will simply stage the changes of the commit before the reset.

An alternative could have been using the `git reset --soft`. This would leave index and working tree untouched and only reset HEAD, leaving the changes of the last commit ready to be committed again (basically avoiding using `git add` before `git commit`).